# Do windows provide message queue similar to that of UNIX message queues (IPC)

Tags: windows, winapi

I need to develop a message queue for Windows similar to message queue IPC available in Unix but I did some research but didn't found any thing useful.Also, I am not supposed to use any third party or chargeable licenced product.

Comment: I can't quite see what the question is. "I need to develop a message queue". That's a requirement rather than a question.

Answer (score 0):

If both applications have message pumps, you can send messages between them using the [`WM_COPYDATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dataxchg/wm-copydata) message.

If not, you can use [`CreateNamedPipe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winbase/nf-winbase-createnamedpipea) and [`ConnectNamedPipe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa365146.aspx), creating the pipe in message mode.

Please note that `WM_COPYDATA` is synchronous (meaning that the sending application will block until the receiving application has processed the message), if that worries you at all.

Comment: WM_COPYDATA is synchronous

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I doubt that bothers the OP.  He probably just wants to get messages from A to B.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder how you came to reach that judgement.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's not unreasonable, don't you think, and `WM_COPYDATA` provides a nice, straightforward IPC mechanism which works for most simple needs, that's why I mentioned it.

Comment: seems unreasonable to me that a message queue should require synchronous delivery. Why require the sender to wait for the message to be processed? Is that what UNIX message queues do? How well do you know UNIX message queues?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Well now the OP knows, let him decide, but the point I wanted to make is that `WM_COPYDATA` is convenient if you can live with it's limitations.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in message queue ([MSMQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms711472.aspx)) on Windows.

Comment: That's a different animal.  It's more akin to email.